# Contagem de paragrafo

Tags: javascript, jquery

PReciso passar um script a um site aonde no conteudo, entre o 3 e o 4 paragrafo, apareça uma publicidade.

Consigo ler qual o 3 paragrafo de um texto e inserir uma DIV apos ela, com JS ou JQUERY?

Comment: Pode colocar parte do HTML, pois para construir o que pede leva-se em consideração a estrutura onde estão os parágrafos, ou se existe um ID, ou classe, etc etc etc..

Answer (score 3):

Pode pegar o parágrafo usando `.eq(índice)` e inserir algo após ele usando `.after()`.

Se o *container* for uma `div` qualquer, pegando pelo `id`:

```js
$(function(){
   var pub = '<div class="pub">publicidade</div>';
   $("#div p:eq(2)").after(pub);
});
// eq(0) = 1º elemento
// eq(1) = 2º elemento 
// eq(2) = 3º elemento ←
// eq(3) = 4º elemento
```

```css
p{
   background: yellow;
}

.pub{
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div">
   <p>parágrafo 1</p>
   <p>parágrafo 2</p>
   <p>parágrafo 3</p>
   <p>parágrafo 4</p>
</div>
```

Se o *container* for o próprio `body`:

```js
$(function(){
   var pub = '<div class="pub">publicidade</div>';
   $("p:eq(2)").after(pub);
});
// eq(0) = 1º elemento
// eq(1) = 2º elemento 
// eq(2) = 3º elemento ←
// eq(3) = 4º elemento
```

```css
p{
   background: yellow;
}

.pub{
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>parágrafo 1</p>
<p>parágrafo 2</p>
<p>parágrafo 3</p>
<p>parágrafo 4</p>
```

- [**Documentação do seletor `:eq()`**](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)
- [**Documentação do método `.after()`**](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

Comment: `.after` até quem arranha inglês desconfia o que seja, agora `.eq` o que seria ?(coisa que vem montado em equino?) rsrs

Comment: rs.. Acho que vem de "equal"... pq tem o seletor `.gt()` que deve significar "_greater than_" (maior que)...

Comment: agora merolho, rs +1

Comment: Prestando bem atenção, vc fala de `.eq` (ponto eq) e no código está `:eq`   (dois pontos eq), e ai?

Comment: As duas coisas são praticamente a mesma coisa, mas vc está certo, e corrigi o link.

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi bem, levando em conta que seus parágrafos estejam dentro de algum container com um identificador, da para fazer com `Jquery` da seguinte forma:

```js
var div = $('<div> Essa é a DIV de propaganda! </div>');
 $('.main').find('p:nth-child(3)').after(div);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="main">
    <p> 1º Parágrafo! </p>
    <p> 2º Parágrafo! </p>
    <p> 3º Parágrafo! </p>
    <p> 4º Parágrafo! </p>
</section>
```

Basta localizar o terceiro parágrafo e após ele, usar a função `after()` para inserir a sua div.

Answer (score 0):

Pode pegar o parágrafo usando `:eq(índice)` e inserir algo após usando `.after()`.

```js
    $( "body" ).find( "div" ).eq( 2 ).addClass( "aliceblue" );

    $(function(){
       var container = '<div>publicidade</div>';
       $("p:eq(2)").after(container);
    });

        $( "div" ).eq(1).css( "background-color", "yellow" );

        $( "div:eq(0)" ).css( "color", "red" );
```

```css
      div {
        margin: 10px;
        float: left;
        border: 2px solid blue;
      }
      .aliceblue {
        background:aliceblue;
      }
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div>zero</div>
    <div>um</div>

    <div>dois
    <p>parágrafo 1</p>
    <p>parágrafo 2</p>
    <p>parágrafo 3</p>
    <p>parágrafo 4</p>
    </div>

    <div>tres</div>
    <div>quatro</div>
```

> repare que `.eq` e `:eq` fazem basicamente a mesma coisa. A diferença entre eles pode ser vista nesse post (ingles) clicando no botão `Run tests` nessa página [**eq vs eq()**](https://jsperf.com/eq-vs-eq/3)